# Dimension based shipping in Magento.

Tags: magento

I need to calculate my shipping based on dimensions. Some of my items are less than 2 pounds but are larger in size.

I googled and found a $240 extension for this but it's too expensive.

Is there any alternative where I can send dimensions to UPS, USPS and Fedex and get the shipping rates from them in my Magento store?

Comment: Sorry, this is off topic on Stack Overflow. Maybe the Magento support forum is the best place to ask this.

Answer (score 2):

Shipping based on dimensions just ends up being reduced back to weight.  Which is why it is called dimensional weight.

http://www.fedex.com/gb/tools/dimweight.html

Basically just enter the dimensional weight or the actual weight of the product when creating your products and shipping will be accurate.

Technically you could program this problem away, but it would be hard to justify the effort.